# mechanize for Java

Tags: java, perl, mechanize

I was wondering if there is something like Perl's/Python's mechanize for Java.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not very knowledgeable in Perl/Python, but if you explain what does this "mechanize" mean , may be we can answer you about java... And what exactly you want to use from mechanize functionality 
I found this - http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/
Is that what you need in Java ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for. In a way like a web-browser, but running in the same process as my app and with an API (and without a GUI)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).  It is similar to Perl's [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm).  There is also a Perl version of it named [WWW::HtmlUnit](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-HtmlUnit/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit.pm) (it uses [Inline::Java](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline-Java/Java.pod) to expose the Java library's methods to Perl).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is now! I too wanted mechanize in Java and we've written it.

Please check out http://gistlabs.com/software/mechanize-for-java/ (and the GitHub here https://github.com/GistLabs/mechanize).

Feedback, bug reports, and success stories welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of a generalized web client, like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)?

Comment: more like HttpClient + TagSoup + Rhino all in one package with an easy-to-use API.